# How to enforce docker client use ipv4

Tags: docker

```
Client:
 Version:           20.10.24+dfsg1
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.19.8
 Git commit:        297e128
 Built:             Thu May 18 08:38:34 2023
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.24+dfsg1
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.19.8
  Git commit:       5d6db84
  Built:            Thu May 18 08:38:34 2023
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.6.20~ds1
  GitCommit:        1.6.20~ds1-1+b1
 runc:
  Version:          1.1.5+ds1
  GitCommit:        1.1.5+ds1-1+b1
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:
```

First: I have no ipv6 network but my http proxy dose. So

```
export http_proxy=http://1.2.3.4:56789
export https_proxy=http://1.2.3.4:56789
export HTTP_PROXY=http://1.2.3.4:56789
export HTTPS_PROXY=http://1.2.3.4:56789
```

And test it with curl:

```
curl https://ipv6.vm3.test-ipv6.com
[1] 975
[2] 976
callback(xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx)
```

But when:

```
docker pull alpine
Error response from daemon: Head "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/alpine/manifests/latest": dial tcp [2600:1f18:2148:bc02:2640:1b90:cea6:b6b5]:443: connect: network is unreachable
```

Even I turn Ipv6 off in sysctl, Docker client still incredibly stubborn use IPv6 and ignore my dns or networking config.

Question: How to make docker client surrender then use ipv4 networking ?

BTW: I'm 100% sure docker client honor the http-proxy variable, So I can't understand what changed in last 6 month.

Comment: `100% sure docker client honor the http-proxy variable` You have to configure docker deamon, not client. Diusable ipv6 - https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/ do `ipv6:false` in /etc/docker/daemon.json, but I stil l think it may use ipv6 to download.

Comment: @KamilCuk  About 6 month ago, I use docker client with variable, And client honor the http-proxy pass the proxy config to dameon which is in the document, But not working now